# Compare 2 column values and highlight if the difference is more then 10%?

Tags: python, pandas, styling

i have a dataframe, where i want to compare 2 values like A compare A2, B compare B2, C compare C2,
I want to calculate the difference in percentage `abs(A2 - A)/A2 * 100`. Now i want to write it in excel with highted as red if 
difference is more than 10%

```
  Cols/Rows    A    A2    B    B2    C    C2
0         A   50    50   150    150  200   200
1         B  200    200  250    300  300   300
2         C  350    500  400    400  450   450
```

My approach is to iterate each row and calculate %

```
for index, row in difference_df.iterrows():
    print(abs(row['A2'] - row['A'])/row['A2'] * 100) # for all columns
```

Also, how to apply color if % is more then 10
I also looked styling

```
def highlight_cells():
    # provide your criteria for highlighting the cells here
    return ['background-color: yellow']

df.style.apply(highlight_cells)
```

But how to apply this styling and write it to excel?

Answer (score 2):

I think need `DataFrame of styles` only by original `DataFrame` columns and index and set rows by condition with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = '' 
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #define columns names 
    cols = ['A','B','C']
    for c in cols:
        m = ((x[c + '2'] - x[c])/x[c + '2'] * 100 ) > 10
        df1.loc[m, [c, c + '2']] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Is it good to use xlsxwriter for such task, or should I use pandas styling?

Comment: Hmmm, I think if create new column with percentage data, is possible format this new column, check [working with conditional formats](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html). But if need dynamic conditions like in my answer, need styling with [export to excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel)

Comment: Yes, I need dynamic conditions. My real dataframe is multi-indexed, let me try with that

Comment: @TarunK - If there is Multiindex, is possible change data sample, if some problem with my solution?